# Upgrade for LGA775

Tags: motherboard, desktop, performance

I have an almost 8 year old PC with LGA 775 socket, I want to somehow upgrade it and use as a web development machine, I need to run Photoshop, adobe illustrator, visual studio and android studio.

following are the screenshots taken using CPU Z
Please suggest upgrade of Processor, RAM and can I use SSD in this ?
Also does graphics card helps in photoshop, android studio?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The socket for the CPU is like 4 "generations" behind the current standard, the RAM us two "generations" behind. The drive ports will be 1-2 gens behind (meaning they'll limit SSDs). You seriously should consider a new(er) mainboard.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend getting a secondhand Core 2 Quad Q9650 or Core 2 Quad X9650 (for your purposes, they're all the same CPU, just with different branding).  This will give you almost double the single-threaded performance, and four times the multi-threaded performance.  You can find them on Ebay for $20-$60.

You'll also want to upgrade your RAM to 4 GB ($60 or so), install a 64-bit version of Windows so you can use all of it, and install a SSD.  Your board is compatible with SATA SSDs, though since the connectors are SATA II rather than SATA III, you won't get the best possible performance.

Comment: Thanks I will try to get the processor, and I think SATA || can operate at 1GBPS or more and typical SSDs have max 550 mbps so SATA || should not be a bottleneck

Comment: Do you have any idea about graphics card which helps for photoshop photo editing

Comment: @codemirror, make sure you've got your bits and bytes straight.  SATA II has a raw transfer rate of 3 giga*bits* per second and 8b/10b encoding, for a top speed of 300 mega*bytes* per second.  For comparison, a Crucial BX300 advertises reading 550 mega*bytes* per second -- you lose almost half of the potential read speed with SATA II.  Still much better than a hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

You could upgrade to a quad core processor and 4GB of RAM if you intend to keep the motherboard. CPUs codenamed Yorkfield were the latest you could get for the 775 platform (they are about USD 40 on ebay), but make sure that you can fit a sufficient cooler in your case to cool the additional 2 cores and higher clock speed. I don't see a reason why you shouldn't be able run SATA SSDs with this machine, the only limitation appears to be the 2 RAM slots, 4 would be better I think.

Here is the product page for the board: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-G31M-S2L-rev-10#sp

Answer (score 1):

You can install the modified s771 CPU.
Modified xeons is much cheaper with the same performance.
[image: xeon s775]
Even if you have the SATA 2 in you system you can use ssd for the swap and it will be as a RAM.